# Model form rules and validation in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

For example I have model form `MySubmitForm`:

```
use yii\base\Model;

class MySubmitForm extends Model{


    public $value1;
    public $value2;
    public $value3;

    public function rules(){
         return [['value1', 'value2'],'required'];
    }

}
```

Here I have two required parameters (`$value1`, `$value2`) and I want one of them to be *required* or I want to user got  error only when both `$value1` and `$value2` would be empty.

Can I achieve this from this form model?

Comment: just added an answer for you see if that helps you out.

Comment: very useful answer

Comment: glad i could help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom validation function inside your validation rules.

Possible options:

**1)** Select the most important relevant field and add error to it.

**2)** Select multiple important relevant fields and add the same error message to them (we can store and pass message in a separate variable before passing to keep code DRY).

**3)** We can use not existing attribute name for adding error, let's say `all` because attribute existence is not checked at that point.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [['value1', 'value2'],'yourCustomValidationMethod'];
}

public function yourCustomValidationMethod()
{
    // Perform custom validation here regardless of "name" attribute value and add error when needed
    if ($this->value1=='' && $this->value2=='') {
        //either use session flash 
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','You need to provide one of the fields');

        //or use model error without any specific field name 
        $this->addError('all', 'Your error message');
    }            
}
```

***Note you can use either `session flash` or `model` to notify the error use which every you like***